# How can I add a blur background and popup view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uivisualeffectview

I wanted to have a blurred background and view popups in my application. But blur background and view is not appearing when I clicked my button.... can anyone please help me to achieve this task...
My codes are

```
- (IBAction)ButtonTouched:(id)sender {

if(!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()){
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    UIVisualEffectView *blureffectview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    blureffectview.frame = self.view.bounds;
    blureffectview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    //[self.view addSubview:blureffectview];
    [self.view insertSubview:_AnimatedViewForLoading aboveSubview:blureffectview];


}else{
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}



UIView * AnimatedViewForLoading;
 //   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 318, 200, 150)];
self.AnimatedViewForLoading.frame = CGRectMake(118, 318, 200, 150);
[self.AnimatedViewForLoading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
self.AnimatedViewForLoading.alpha = 0.0f;
//AnimatedViewForLoading.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;

self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
 [self.view addSubview:self.AnimatedViewForLoading];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    NSLog(@"oopssssss..........");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
        self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

- Why doesn't blur background appear? - Because you didn't add it to `self.view`

  ```
  //[self.view addSubview:blureffectview];
  ```
- Why doesn't `AnimatedViewForLoading` appear? - Because you added it to `self.view` before it's initialized and `self.AnimatedViewForLoading.alpha` is set to 0.0f

  ```
  // self.AnimatedViewForLoading is hidden at this line
  self.AnimatedViewForLoading.alpha = 0.0f;

  // |_AnimatedViewForLoading| is initialized after this line
  [self.view insertSubview:_AnimatedViewForLoading aboveSubview:blureffectview];
  ```

### Solution

```
- (IBAction)ButtonTouched:(id)sender {
  //  UIView * AnimatedViewForLoading;
  //   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 318, 200, 150)];
  self.AnimatedViewForLoading = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(118, 318, 200, 150)];
  [self.AnimatedViewForLoading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
  // self.AnimatedViewForLoading.alpha = 0.0f;
  //AnimatedViewForLoading.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;

  // if(!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()){
  // self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    UIVisualEffectView *blureffectview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    blureffectview.frame = self.view.bounds;
    blureffectview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:blureffectview];
    [self.view insertSubview:_AnimatedViewForLoading aboveSubview:blureffectview];
  // }else{
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  // }

  self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);

  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    NSLog(@"oopssssss..........");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
      self.AnimatedViewForLoading.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
  }];
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to check `UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled` but maybe the code inside if statement wasn't run. I updated my answer. You can try again and let me know what happen

Comment: still not achieve it...all view controller become black and button disappeared now......

Comment: Seem like you have another additional problem. It's better if you can add the project to question or I can help you to debug it through teamviewer

Comment: @RKios you can check my updated answer. You forgot initializing `AnimatedViewForLoading`.

Comment: here is the [URL]( we.tl/7mO39fxZfC)

Comment: its working buddy thanks a lot for specifying my mistakes @trungduc